# Why is Hibernate setting a foreign key to a null value?

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3.0.5, Java 6, MySQL 5.5. I thought I had everything set up correctly, but clearly I do not.

Here are the class mappings:

```
<class name="com.rc.model.partner.Partner" table="partner">
    ...
    <set name="pacChannelSet" table="pac_channel" lazy="false" cascade="all">
        <key column="partnerid"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.rc.model.partner.PacChannel"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="com.rc.model.partner.PacChannel" table="pac_channel">
    ...
    <many-to-one name="partner" class="com.rc.model.partner.Partner" column="partnerid"
                 foreign-key="partnerid" cascade="none"/>
</class>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
pacChannelDAO.saveOrUpdate(pacChannel1);
partner.addPacChannel(pacChannel1);
pacChannelDAO.saveOrUpdate(pacChannel2);
partner.addPacChannel(pacChannel2);
partnerDAO.saveOrUpdate(partner);
```

Here are the debug statements, indicating an attempt to nullify the partnerid in the pac_channel table, and error that results:

```
11:27:07,088 DEBUG [SQL] update partner set ... where partnerid=? and updateddate=?
11:27:07,165 DEBUG [SQL] update pac_channel set partnerid=?, channelname=?, apikey=?, active=?, dailyrequestlimit=? where pacchannelid=?
11:27:07,193 DEBUG [SQL] update pac_channel set partnerid=?, channelname=?, apikey=?, active=?, dailyrequestlimit=? where pacchannelid=?
11:27:07,300 DEBUG [SQL] update pac_channel set partnerid=null where partnerid=? and pacchannelid=?
11:27:07,413 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mexp`.`pac_channel`, CONSTRAINT `chan_partnerid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`partnerid`) REFERENCES `partner` (`partnerid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Why is Hibernate generating the last SQL statement with "set partnerid=null"? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use XML to map my entities, but I think your mapping is wrong. The one side should be the inverse side of the many side, as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-m21):

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="address" 
        column="addressId"
        not-null="true"/>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="people" inverse="true">
        <key column="addressId"/>
        <one-to-many class="Person"/>
    </set>
</class>
```